# Fastest directory size on Android

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, filesystems, filesize

I can calculate directory size using

```kotlin
val sz = Path("""path/to/directory""").walk().sumOf { it.fileSize() }
```

But apparently, it's not fast enough, it's very slow.

MiXplorer lists all directory sizes very fast, so I know a faster way is possible (It seems as if the info was already stored by OS and it just retried it somehow). But unfortunately it's closed-sourced.

I'd appreciate any known faster methods, thanks.